# representation theory on algebraically closed field

Tags: representation-theory

I was trying to show that the only finite dimensional division algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ is $\mathbb{C}$. But start with some assumptions but couldn't proceed.

I begin by letting $D$ to be any divison ring and finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}-$ algebra. Then I let an irreducible representation $\rho :\mathbb{C}\rightarrow GL(D)$ by $z(d)\mapsto zd$. $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed.

How can I proceed with that and the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ algebraic closdness of $\mathbb{C}$ or is there some simple method to prove it using the concept of irreducible representation? Thank you

Comment: It is not quite clear what representation of what are you trying to use.

Answer (score 2):

Such an algebra is a simple left module for itself.

For a non-zero element $a$, multiplication by $a$ on the right gives a homomorphism of left modules, which is the multiplication by a complex number by Schur.

Hence that element was already a complex number, and the algebra itself is just the complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

(This answer is **wrong**; see comments. It's left here as a possible guide for others as clueless as I am.)

I don't think the thing you're trying to prove is true. Aren't the quaternions a 2-dimensional division algebra over $\Bbb C$, under the map $(z, w) \mapsto z + {\mathbf j}w$?

Comment: I want to say the only  division ring  which is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}-$algebra is $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: No, the quaternions do not form an algebra over $\Bbb C$. (Recall an $R$-algebra $A$ is in effect a ring homomorphism from $R$ to the centre of $A$.)

Comment: Thanks, @LordSharktheUnknown; your use of "recall" is pretty charitable -- my algebra was never very strong, and has (evidently) worsened with age. I'm going to leave this answer and your comment as possibly helpful to others who might share my misperceptions.

Comment: downvoted, because I don't think the comments do enough to highlight the fact that this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: Good point.  Presumably my edit to the answer will satisfy you.

Comment: @JohnHughes indeed. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $\mathbb C \subset D$ is a finite-dimensional division algebra, where by defintion $\mathbb C \subset Z(D)$, then for $x \in D-\mathbb C$, $\mathbb C(x)$ is a finite-dimensional *commutative* division algebra extending $\mathbb C$.